# moderncv and missing begin{document}

Tags: moderncv

i built my CV half a year ago and everything worked fine back then. Now that I am trying to recompile it, it seems to have simply broken down and I cant tell why...
The most minimal not working version I managed to brake it into (without deleting too much hopefully) is this:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{romannum}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{palatino}

\moderncvtheme[blue]{classic}               

\usepackage[scale=0.84]{geometry}
\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{2.8cm}    
\AtBeginDocument{\setlength{\maketitlenamewidth}{6cm}}
\AtBeginDocument{\recomputelengths} 

% personal data
\name{z}{o}
\title{Curriculum Vitae}
\address{A}{i}
\mobile{98978}        
\email{blabla@test.de}

\photo[100pt]{img/profil}       

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

The errors are.

```
 Undefined control sequence. \begin{document}
Missing number, treated as zero. \begin{document}
Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted). \begin{document}
You have requested package `moderncvheadi', but the package provides `moderncvheadi'.
You have requested package `moderncvbodyi', but the package provides `moderncvbodyi'.
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph
```

I am using Win 7 with miktex. I have tried updating all available packages so far and reinstalling moderncv, but nothing helps. As I said, this has already worked a few months ago...

Anybody know how to deal with this?

Regards,
Michael

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The length `maketitlenamewidth` doesn't seem to exist anymore. So remove the line:

```
\AtBeginDocument{\setlength{\maketitlenamewidth}{6cm}}
```

Comment: that indeed was the problem...thanks for making the effort!